# How to iterate back a for loop to the last index it visited in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I have an array of integer, and i am trying to iterate back the for loop to the last index it visited based on some condition , Lets say i have `2 9 15 19 23 28 37` elements in that loop i am giving a condition that if each element of that loop is greater than a number lets say 8 , it will process that element again.

Here my code is

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int n = 6;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int h = 8;
    int r = a[i] - h;
    if (r <= 0) {
        result.add(1);
    } else if (r >= 0) {
        result.add(1);
    }
}
```

Here h is the array which holds the declared elements.r is an integer that checks if elements are greater than the hit element i.e 8.So the condition is if the elements are less that h the arraylist will add 1, else the control will go back to the operation int r = a[i] -h, for the same element.For example , 2 is less that 8 the arraylist will add 1 , but for 9 the control will do that same minus operation and come to the else part and add 1 to the arraylist.The last element processed by the loop if not zero will not be added to the list.Is is possible? please help.

Comment: To process an element again on the next iteration, do `i--`. That way, when loop does `i++`, you end up with same `i` value and will process the same element again.

Comment: @Andreas This would lead to an infinite loop because `a[i]` is not changed. So again `r = 1` and so on

Comment: can anyone please help with the solution ?? Didn't get the required answer yet

Comment: *"a condition that if each element of that loop is greater than a number lets say 8 , it will process that element again"* — Could you edit your question and tell us the desired output by a known input? It's not completely clear what the requirements are. Do you want to process element `e` a certain number of times *only* when `e` is greater than threshold `t`?

Comment: @MCEmperor I will edit the question with some example outputs

Comment: Some things required to answer the question are as follows: **1** • Are the elements related? Or must each element meet some condition individually? **2** • Must the elements be processed in order? Or doesn't it matter in which order elements are processed?

Answer (score 2):

You could be returned a step back by `--i`:

```
if (a[i] - h > 0) {
    // a[i] is greater than h
    --i; // process a[i] again on the next iteration
}
```

As [@Stefan Warminski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7707631/stefan-warminski) noticed it will lead to an infinite loop because we always will process the first element than is greater than the `h`.

The workaround could be creating an array `int[] changes` the same length as the origin list and putting a value into an appropriate cell which will indicate how many times `changes[i]` we process an `a[i]` element:

```
if (a[i] - h > 0 && changes[i]++ < N) { ... }
```

where `N` is how many times you want to process an element.

Complete code snippet:

```
int[] a = {2, 9, 15, 19, 23, 28, 37};
int[] changes = new int[a.length];

int h = 8;
int N = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] - h > 0 && changes[i]++ < N) {
        System.out.println(a[i] + " is processed " + changes[i] + " times");
        --i;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
9 is processed 1 times
9 is processed 2 times
15 is processed 1 times
15 is processed 2 times
19 is processed 1 times
19 is processed 2 times
23 is processed 1 times
23 is processed 2 times
28 is processed 1 times
28 is processed 2 times
37 is processed 1 times
37 is processed 2 times
```

Tip: declare the `h` variable outside the `for` statement, it won't change inside (there is no need to create a variable on every iteration).

Comment: Since `a[i]` is not changed this leads to an infinite loop

Comment: @AndrewTobilko i am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in result.add(1) after decrementing i

Comment: @Mandrek, have you tried my workaround? I added my complete code snippet

Comment: @AndrewTobilko how 37 can be processed 2 times I have the condition that until it is zero it is not added to the else part

Comment: @Mandrek, `37` is greater than `8`, so it was

Comment: @AndrewTobilko but after processing 2 times it is not zero I have to add those elements which  will zero after processing.See the requirement is add those which are either less that zero or equal to zero

Comment: @Mandrek, in the sample, you are performing the same `result.add(1)` action, `else if (r >= 0)` makes no sense because the `==` check is already above

Comment: @AndrewTobilko and what about 2 I have a condition that which elements are less that h also to be stored somewhere and also which are greater than h , but until the greater elements are zero.Please read my question

Comment: @Mandrek, I really didn't catch what the `List<Integer> result` should contain

Comment: @AndrewTobilko you don't need to consider List<Integer>result , just help me building the logic that if  elements are less that h=8 then there will be a count and also if those elements are greater that 8 until they become zero/0 or less than zero  then the minus operation will be going and when they will be zero or less than zero there will also be another count for that , and at the end of operation two count will be added .that's  it.I am clear now ??

Answer (score 1):

Note that the test `r<=0` is useless : you can just take `result.add(1)` outside of the tests since you do that operation in any case.

```
int h=8;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int r = a[i] -h;
    result.add(1);
    if(r >=0){
        'loop back'
    }
}
```

Then, if your goal is to "process that element again", do you really need to iterate back ? You already have the element, just process it again.

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int n =6;
int h=8;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int r = a[i] -h;
    result.add(1); // Processed once
    if(r >=0){
        result.add(1); // Processed twice
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int n =6;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int h=8;
    int r = a[i] -h;
    if(r <=0){
        result.add(1);
    }else if(r >=0){
        result.add(1); 
        i--;           
    }
}
```

Using this code you can process the number greater than 8 again.If r>=0 then i is decremented and the numbers greater than 8 is processed again.

Comment: It would be better if you could add some explanation to the code you have posted. Only code answers attracts -ve votes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to process an element multiple times, *only* when that element meets some condition.

You can simply loop over the list and then if the element is greater than `h`, you just execute the desired action (in my case `System.out.println()`) an `n` number of times.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(2, 9, 15, 19, 23, 28, 37);

int h = 8;
int n = 2;
list.stream().forEach(t -> {
    int r = (t > h ? n : 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
});
```

Or the below-Java-8 version:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(2, 9, 15, 19, 23, 28, 37);

int h = 8;
int n = 2;
for (int t : list) {
    int r = (t > h ? n : 1); // Execute 'n' times if condition is met,
                             // otherwise, execute once
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        System.out.println(t); // Code you want to execute
    }
}
```

---

Besides,

```
int h = 8;
int r = a[i] - h;
if (r <= 0) {
    result.add(1);
}
else if (r >= 0) {
    result.add(1);
}
```

doesn't make sense. In fact, you are comparing `a[i]` with `h`. The following code has the same effect:

```
int h = 8;
result.add(1);
if (a[i] == h) {
    // Add the number 1 again to the list
    result.add(1);
}
```

Comment: @Mandrek Which Java version are you using? This code requires at least Java 8.

Comment: @Mandrek *"code not compiling"* — What's the error?

Comment: list.stream().forEach(t -> {   Syntax error on tokens, ( expected instead